# Performance-testing according SLA - full page load

Tags: test-design, load-testing, performance-testing

There are many tools allowing performence testing with full page load time parameter monitoring. Problem is I can check a page by pasting its URL.

Suppose I have a website with 100 pages, some of them is only basic html, others read a lot of data from db. I want to make sure my websites stands under the SLA I determined. Most of tools allow monitoring of only one page of my website.

Should I test each page by itself? Isn’t there a more efficient way to test the average full page load time?
Or maybe I have to define each page an expected load time?

Thanks

Comment: What type of tools are you referring to? And what do you want to accomplish exactly? Average per page, aggregated average for the site? Something else?

Comment: I want to know the average time to load pages in the whole site. (According to the comment below  I don’t have to do it as part of load test. Do you agree?)

Answer (score 1):

To start with: everything is context.
If you want to look for a bottleneck you will likely measure differently then when you want to show you comply with a contract (SLA).

I *assume* when you mention tools (as you didn't actually mention any) you mean (free) online services (like Googles [Pageinsight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed) or [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com)) that measure your serving speed. Which is probably fine when developing for only a few pages. But I would advise tools like [Jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org) or [Gatlin](https://gatling.io) to measure (and load test) your site.

As you seem to want to know if you can deliver what you promise, based on loading speeds, I would suggest to start measuring the overall behaviour of your likely **slowest** pages. the assumption would be that if they respond within your expectations, the simpler pages will in all likelihood perform similar or faster. You can spot check a few of them.

The way you test this is also dependent on your site. Is there a logical flow that users would follow? Or is it only a lot of semi-independent pages? You can start with only the bare pages and add complexity in traversing through your site to emulate real life behaviour.

But there is more that you need to factor in:

- how many average concurrent users do you expect (according to the SLA)?
- how many users do you expect during spikes?
- which pages will likely get the most visitors at any given moment?
- what types of clients (mobile? desktop? other?)
- is your test environment comparable to the production?
- what specifics are agreed upon in the SLA?
- and so on..

So at one point you think you know what your system can handle.But it may run out of steam.

If you are in production, you measure information (like Paul suggested) that show you the day-to-day, second-to-second operation of the site. And act based on what it tells you.

**Most importantly: you wouldn't want to performance test your production site (EVER!) and cripple it while doing it.**

Answer (score 0):

Some basic understanding of a load test:

- Load Tests should simulate a real user
- Load Tests should focus on production-like scenarios

What it sounds like you're asking for is something to monitor the average load time of a web-page which is not really what a load test is supposed to do. This type of data is easier to track using something like [AppDynamics](https://www.appdynamics.com/). Load tests are more designed to tell you how your applications performs and usually helps in identifying areas where you application can be improved or bottlenecks within your application.

While overall response time is a great indicator and something that executives love to hear about, in reality within the technical side of things you should be more focused on things like RAM consumption, CPU consumption, IO rates and such. This is what will allow you to identify why the response times are what they are and give you an idea of where to look to reduce those response times.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! So when I run a load test I have to compare the results to my LSA - RAM, CPU etc. Just to make sure - You said that load tests help to find bottlenecks but from what I know, stress test (which is kind of sub test of load test) does this job in case the load test fails in one or more parameters, am I right?